# Selenium: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process' error after upgrading Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, anaconda

All of sudden I am getting error:

```
x/webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/anaconda3/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 

Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x101f92b00>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 163, in __del__
    self.stop()
  File "/anaconda3/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 135, in stop
    if self.process is None:
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
```

It was not the issue before.

Comment: Did you download executable geckodriver and provide the PATH into system variable before launching firefox?? Could you share your tried code as well??

Comment: Hope [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path/40208762#40208762) helps you. Thanks

Comment: @SaurabhGaur No But why is it needed now?

Comment: Firefox 48+ requires geckodriver as Firefox now requires extensions to be signed. (The firefox driver that was built into selenium was just an extension). Selenium 3.0+ defaults to using geckodriver so it expects it to be there. If you want to use the old firefox driver with a Firefox version less than 48, you can pass the capability `{marionette: False}` to use the old firefox driver